# asymptotic of an interesting recurrence realtion (more general case)

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers

A link to the original question for reference:Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250720/asymptotic-of-an-interesting-recurrence-relation/1412256#1412256)

I tried to study a more general situation:

Let $y_{d,d}=1$ and 
$$
y_{n+1,d}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(ny_{n,d}+\left(1+y_{n,d}-y_{n,d-1}\right)^{-n}\right),
$$
where $n,d\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge d$.

Using the arguments from the original problem (cf. the link above) (with some modifications), we have
$$
y_{n,d}<dy_{n,1}\;\;\mbox{for all}\;\;n\ge d.
$$
This imples that $y_{n,d}<\frac{d(Log(n)+1)}{n}$  for all  $n\ge d$.

I made an initial attempt (induction) and guessed the lower bound, i.e.
$$
y_{n,d}>\frac{d(H_n-H_d)}{n}\;\mbox{for all}\;n\ge d,
$$
where $H_n$ is the harmonic series ($H_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}$).

Although I can't prove this now, the numerical results really supports this conjecture. Furthermore, I conjectured that
$$
y_{n,d}\sim\frac{dLog(n)}{n}\;\mbox{as}\;n\to\infty.
$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.